# UITextField in UIView in UIAlertView not working?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

In my iPhone application, If I add uitextfield in uialertview it works fine bt if i add it into uiview and if uiview is added into uialertview it is nt working. Getting strange behiviour?
Please help, If any one know about that! Thank you.
**Note:** here UItextField not working means- it is not taking any input but interesting is that if click on it keyboard appears, also its delegate are not gets calling.

Comment: What kind of behavior are you getting (Any screenshots or something )?
->Check the frame of your UIView.

Comment: Refer this [blog](http://rajendrabhole.blogspot.com/) It may be help you.

Comment: Here tf is nt working means, it is not taking any input, as well its delegtes r not getting calling..

Comment: @RPB: I have added uitextview in uialertview successfully even textview is clickable bt it is nt taking any input and also its delegates are not working

Answer (score 1):

just add a temp textField in ur alerView below the view of yours

```
      tf = [[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease]; 
      [alertView addSubView:tf];
```

in your alertView and every thing will work good ..... this is just to inform alertView that there is some view in it that need to be first responder at some point of time

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. i tried change size of frames. this code isn't really good, but works for me:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    self.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 284, 248);
    int i = 0;
    for (UIView*classW in  self.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([classW class]) isEqualToString:@"UIThreePartButton"]) {
            classW.frame = CGRectMake(11+135*i, 189, 127, 43);
            i++;
        }

        if ([NSStringFromClass([classW class]) isEqualToString:@"UIView"]) {
            classW.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            CGRect f = classW.frame;
            f.size.height += 30;
            classW.frame = f;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just created a post, which can solve your problem.

**Key:** You need to add a fake UITextfield via coding behind your view, in order to make your other UITextfields in your customized view to capture inputs from Keyboard. I don't why, but it works.

http://creiapp.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-add-uitextfield-to-uialertview.html